# Difference between GCC & Clang regarding overload resolution for overloaded & templated stream operator<<

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, operator-overloading

The following code works as expected with GCC 9 (C++17 mode):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace OtherNs {
    
    struct OtherType { int data = 42; };

    // here I have a generic template overload for any ostream-compatible stream
    template <typename Ostream>
    Ostream& operator<<(Ostream& stream, const OtherType& in) {
        stream << "OtherType" << in.data << "\n";
        return stream;
    }
}

namespace MyNs {

    template <typename T>
    void toStream(std::ostream& s, const T& value) {
        // here I want to use operator<< for whatever T is
        s << value;
    }

    struct PrinterType {
        template <typename T>
        PrinterType& operator<<(const T& in) {
            toStream(std::cout, in);
            return *this;
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    MyNs::PrinterType mt;

    // here I want to use only PrinterType::operator<<
    mt << "prefix: " << OtherNs::OtherType();
}
```

but fails to compile with Clang 9 with the following error:

```
../scripts/playground/test.cpp:45:22: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'MyNs::PrinterType' and 'OtherNs::OtherType')
    mt << "prefix: " << OtherNs::OtherType();
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../scripts/playground/test.cpp:18:14: note: candidate function [with Ostream = MyNs::PrinterType]
    Ostream& operator<<(Ostream& stream, const OtherType& in) {
             ^
../scripts/playground/test.cpp:34:22: note: candidate function [with T = OtherNs::OtherType]
        PrinterType& operator<<(const T& in) {
                     ^
```

Why is there a difference between the 2 compilers?

Comment: note that `std::ostream` is one of the rare cases where the standard library relies on inheritance. Typically you just use `std::ostream&` and rely on output streams to inherit from it. Or do you have some particular reason to make the type of the stream a template parameter?

Comment: The target is a little old, but I don't think anything's changed in C++17. Also, I don't think the extra indirection with the namespaces makes any difference.

Comment: I'm trying to resolve this problem in my testing framework:
https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/pull/431
Someone is trying to use doctest with a codebase which already has `operator<<` overloads but they are templated on the stream - as can be seen here: https://github.com/biojppm/c4core/commit/ccec630a34f63b2bfe371ca3d84bd1d9092d55fd#diff-83915d448e8e38e2526b8c61e3dab466bdea592fe8261f7e6a3b6759fdc13730L1586

Comment: @idclev463035818 @cigien not sure who flagged this as a duplicate to the other one, but whatever is there does not resolve my problem. The trick with `any` actually makes it choose the other overload and not the one I want, as @T.C. rightfully [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110429/ambiguous-operator-overload-on-clang#comment39079107_25110429)

And the other "solution" requires a change to the call site - by explicitly adding the `operator` keyword as in [here: `(comma_guard().operator,(foo()));`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25110733/3162383) - and that's not an option...

Comment: not sure, but afaik you can only ping one user in a comment. You should be able to see in the above message that @cigien closed as duplicate. As far as I can see the questions are really about the same issue, but i have to admit that I didnt really bother to understand it in all details, hence I can't say much about what is a solution and what not

Comment: As mentioned in the comment by idclev, please ping the user who closes the question as a duplicate, in order to notify them. The target looks like it's asking the same question. If the answers there are not suitable, then consider placing a bounty on that question. If you feel that your question itself is different, then please edit your question explaining why.